# Sorting an array of structs by particular members of said structs?

Tags: c++

So basically, I have a *struct* that, along with other members, has *x*, *y* and *z* values to represent a 3D point; I have then a vector of said structs which is built by some functions.

```
struct myStruct{
    char x;
    char y;
    char z;
    // some other members
};

vector<myStruct> myVector = myVectorBuildingFunction(...);
```

Now, I would like to sort the structs in the vector by the distance between their 3D point (x, y, z members) and another variable point in the space.. is that possible without rebuilding the structs' members one by one (they're relatively many) or remaking entirely my initial vector building function?

Comment: Why the DirectX tag? This is a question about sorting a struct - the fact that you might be using it in DX is not relevant to the question.

Comment: Whoops, right. Pardon me.. it's the habit!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `std::sort` with lambdas, like this:

```
myStruct pointOfInterest = ...; // Set the point of interest
sort(mMyClassVector.begin(), mMyClassVector.end(), 
    [&](const myStruct & lhs, const myStruct & rhs) -> bool
{
    double distanceLhs = computeDistance(pointOfInterest, lhs);
    double distanceRhs = computeDistance(pointOfInterest, rhs);
    return distanceLhs < distanceRhs;
});
```

Comment: Or can overload the `operator()` in the structure, if this is what you will be taking as a comparision metric for complete course of your program. Just a suggestion.

Comment: @AmanDeepGautam That would be harder, because you would need to store the point of interest inside the comparator structure. Lambdas provide a more concise approach to this problem.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I am kind of confused here with the statement "distance between their 3D point" in the question. I think everything is in the structure itself is what OP meant. I may be wrong. I know it is intuitive to find distance from some other point(like origin) but I am not sure if it is that metric here.

Comment: @AmanDeepGautam My understanding is that `myStruct` has other members in addition to `x`, `y`, and `z`. The first three members represent "their point", the rest of the members are not used for comparison.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Yup, that's exactly what I meant. Er pardon me, is computeDistance() a function I have to write or is it an actual function..?

Comment: @Banderi Yes, that's a function that you need to write. This could be a member function on the `myStruct` as well, and it does not have to take `myStruct` as a second parameter - a 3D point would work as well.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight apparently what you understood was correct. I think sometimes we should just go by intuition..:)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible using comparator function or [functors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356950/c-functors-and-their-uses).

```
struct byDistTo {
   myStruct point;
   byDistTo(myStruct point): point(point){}
   bool operator() (const& myStruct a, const& myStruct b) const {
     // define getDistance yourself
     return getDistance(a, point) < getDistance(b, point); 
   }
}
```

And later call std::sort:

```
vector<myStruct> myVector = myVectorBuildingFunction(...);
myStruct point = {1,2,3}; // define that 'another varialbe`
std::sort(myVector.begin(), myVector.end(), byDistTo(point));
```

Comment: It is better to define `by_dist` in the scope of `myStruct`. isn't it?